# Check if Ubuntu is being installed on VM

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I am trying to automate ubuntu installation from a network repository. I am now succesfully able to configure the iso image and it does the installation automatically.

**My requirement:**

I would like to know if there is a method in the initial installation stage of ubuntu, where I can know if the OS being installed on virtualbox or a physical desktop. I want this check to be performed as I want to automate the installation of virtualbox guest addition if the installation is being performed on a virtualbox.

If any one here have any experience with the same, please share your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/) to detect whether you are running on bare-metal or some hypervisor.